# Is there way to use styled component conditions and css variable with calc?

Tags: css, webpack, styled-components, css-variables

I am trying to use css variable in calc. it works fine when there is no condition in the calc. However, if it has styled component condition. it does not seem to calculate.
Is this issue related to the styled-component cannot use post css ?

This works

```
  margin-top: calc(10px + var(--header-height));
```

This doesnt work

```
 margin-top: calc(10px + var(--header-height) + ${({ condition }) => condition ? 10 : 0} px;
```

Is there anyway to make this work?

webpack config for the post css

```
 {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions:{
                plugins: [
                  postcssCustomProperties(),
                  'postcss-modules-values',
                  calc(),
                  'postcss-nested',
                  'autoprefixer',
                ]
              }
            }
          }
```

post css related library

```
"postcss": "^8.4.4",
"postcss-calc": "^8.0.0",
"postcss-custom-properties": "^12.0.0",
"postcss-loader": "^4.0.0",
"postcss-modules-values": "^3.0.0",
"postcss-nested": "4.1.2",
```

Answer (score 1):

It will be working. Wrap margin-top property value in template literals.

```
const Component = styled.div`
 margin-top: ${condition => `calc(10px + var(--header-height) + ${condition ? 10 : 0}px)`};
`

const App = () =>
  <div>
    <Component condition={true}>Component</Component>
  </div>;
```